# your experience using symfony 2.0

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony1, symfony

I'm going to start a new project that's building web apps from scratch.

I have been thinking about using symfony framework for this project.

Should I start using symfony 2.0 or stick with 1.4 ? I estimate this project will be finish on May or June this year but I realise that symfony 2.0 still on development.

Which one I should use ? I want it to be flexible as possible. I heard also that symfony 2.0 faster than the previous one ...

Anyone has experience with symfony 2.0 (beta) for current project ? what do you think ? should I use it or may be should I move to another framework (I consider about kohanaphp as the back up)

Comment: This is outdated -- symfony 2 has now been released

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the "**[Read and learn](http://symfony-reloaded.org/learn)**" page of the **[symfony-reloaded](http://symfony-reloaded.org/)** website :

> Please note that Symfony 2 is **not
>   yet ready for production**. The final
>   release is planned for **late 2010**
>   and will only support PHP 5.3.2. In
>   the meantime, we highly encourage you
>   to use the current [symfony 1.4](http://www.symfony-project.org/) 
>   stable release for all your projects.

If the authors of Symfony themselves say that Symfony 2.0 should not be used now -- well, I suppose you shouldn't use it ;-)

Especially if your project should be finished something like 6 month before the date when SYmfony 2.0 stable will be released !

Comment: I know about that, I know also that there is risk on using "not yet ready" one. But I would love to use the latest tech for my project so that in the future I don't need worry about migrating to new 2.0 version.

Comment: I understand how you feel ; but using a **Preview release**, which is not even a Beta, for a project that will has to be finished several months before the stable version of the framework... Well... Sounds dangerous to me : what if something big changes before that stable version ? You'll have to migrate from "release" *(with no support)* to "stable" ; it is better than migrating from "stable 1.4" (with support) to "stable 2.0" ?

Comment: @nightingale2k1 I agree with Pascal and just in case you are also considering Doctrine 2: same thing. not ready for production yet.

Answer (score 2):

I use Symfony2 for production, and there is no problem.
Final release will be out at the end of the month.
I think you should use it, as it's completly different from sf1.4 and REALY better!

Answer (score 0):

I have been building a Symfony 2 application that is going into production next week!  I started developing on PR11 and have been updating the codebase as each beta has been released.

This has been relatively pain free, just update the vendors folder then making any necessary changes to your code as some things change  (usually just quicker and easier ways of doing the same thing, or some method renaming).

Bugs get found quickly by the community so as long as you keep updating your vendor directory I believe it's stable enough to start building with.  Stable release is due July:

[Symfony2 Beta 5 available, stable release for July](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-beta5-available)